# Python how to get null padded byte string from unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

Im sure that someone should be able to help me here, as it feels like such a simple answer, but i can't find it anywhere. I need to write a unicode string (null padded ascii basically), but it isn't working as expected, no matter what i try from the internets, it ends up as pure ascii.

```
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as oFile:
    name = u'AAA'
    oFile.write(name)  //always writing 0x414141 i want 0x410041004100
```

Just to clarify, though the question is answered already, in case someone wanders here, the use case is it is a mixed binary file (an int here, a unicode string there, a struct, etc) and I am editing in place. I really just wanted to be able to write the string the way it is represented in the file ('AAA' as 0x410041004100 instead of 0x414141)

Comment: Wouldn't null-padded `0x41` be `0x0041` instead of `0x4100`?

Comment: What do you mean by "a unicode string (null padded ASCII basically)".  How is unicode the same as null padded?  Do you mean you want to encode it as UTF-16?

Comment: honestly i hardly use unicode so im hardly sure, really what i am looking to do is turn the ascii string into the null padded format I always see, i apologize for not knowing if its utf8 or utf16... what does windows typically use?

Comment: I can do it by hand, but i thought i could get the null padded string naturally from a function already

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16 little-endian internally. That's consistent with what you say you want for a result. It's *not* commonly found in text files.

Comment: @MarkRansom appreciate that. Honestly i always thought the format was utf8 but didn't want to embarrass myself too much on the internets lol, so i just said 'unicode'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.encode()` method with an appropriate codec:

```
>>> name = u"aaa"
>>> name.encode("utf_16")
'\xff\xfea\x00a\x00a\x00'
```

The `\xff\xfe` at the beginning is a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Your application may or may not require that, and you can remove it if not needed.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Appreciate the BOM portion as well :D

Comment: You almost certainly will want to remove the BOM if it's not the very first write to the file.

Comment: Or just use `utf-16le`/`utf-16be`.  They don't add a BOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module to specify an encoding when you open the file:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('test.txt', 'wb', encoding='utf-16') as oFile:
    ...
```

Further information:

- [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Comparison of Unicode encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings)

Comment: I know i didn't specify, but this use case is not good for me, I actually have the file open already and it is a mixed binary file, so to do it this way i would need to close and reopen it multiple times... but thank you :)